# How to simulate foreground service killed by the Android system

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I want to reproduce a scenario where android system kills the service.

In service class I'm posting foreground service notification from `onCreate` and returning **START_REDELIVER_INTENT** from `onStartCommand` method. Below exception I'm getting for some of devices.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
```

As per code, it shouldn't crash as I am posting foreground service notification from `onCreate` and cancelling that notification on service `onDestroy`. The only thing I'm guessing that might possible at some moment android system kills the service and due to that notification get cancelled automatically and service get restarted, and this time `onCreate` may not get called. But on the other side i'm also not sure whether this time(system kill service) onCreate will get called or not, if that get call then it is impossible to get the above exception.